# What I said the nuance of the phrase きっと青春が聞こえる？

Tags: translation, words

In one of my favorite μ's songs, the title is きっと青春が聞こえる. My problem is with the 青春. I think the title means something like "I can surely hear the youth" but that sounds kind of strange. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: 確かそうです。歌詞の全文はここです: http://www.kasi-time.com/item-65317.html

Comment: あの"きっと"は"絶対に"と理解してもいいようです

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, I agree, as a native Japanese it does sound a little off, but then, this is a song, so the bar is a little lower.

I can only imagine that the song is set in the context in which this sounds OK, for example, you were a member of a brass band and every time you hear a trombone, that reminds you of the youth, that kind of thing.

Comment: I wouldn't really say it sounds "off"; I think in poetry it's a little more normal to ascribe properties to things that they wouldn't usually have--in this case, "youth," which is not normally something you think of "hearing." More generally the meaning implied is probably hearing "the sounds of youth" or something similar.

Comment: @Kurausukun so you and I are saying the same thing, right? I don't see the point of disagreement. Lyrics, poetry, there are places in the language where the bar is lower, where expressions that normally do not make sense are intentionally used. The same I gave about a trombone is what you mean by hearing the sounds of youth.